# How to query to API in custom resolver AWS Amplify CLI?

Tags: graphql, aws-cli, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I'd like to fetch data in my custom resolver using the query defined in `graphql.schema`. Is it possible? How could I do the query?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Allow lambda resolver to query my API using:
   `amplify function update` ->
   `Lambda function` ->
   `<lambdaResolverfunctionName>` ->
   `Resource access permissions`->
   `api` ->
   `Query`
2. Fetch data like typical graphQL query:

```
const myResolver = async (event) => {
  const endpoint = process.env.API_<apiName>_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
  const { authorization } = event.request.headers;
  const query = 'query ...';

  const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      authorization
    },
    body: query
  });

  const { data } = await response.json();

  return data;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?